# How to change the value of v-overlay if getters are available in component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuetify.js

In the component of **Vue.js** application I take information from the Vuex storage. Inside that component, I want to show [v-overlay](https://vuetifyjs.com/ru/components/overlays) (preloader) until the data from storage will not be available. How correctly to make it?

```
<template>

  <v-navigation-drawer
    v-model="open"
    absolute
    right>

    <v-overlay
      :absolute="absolute"
      :opacity="opacity"
      :value="overlay">

      <v-progress-circular
        indeterminate
        size="64">
      </v-progress-circular>

    </v-overlay>

    <v-checkbox
      v-if="!overlay"
      hide-details
      v-model="selectedGenders"
      v-for="gender in genders"
      :label="gender"
      :value="gender"
      :key="gender">
    </v-checkbox>

    <v-checkbox
      v-if="!overlay"
      hide-details
      v-model="selectedIncomeRanges"
      v-for="incomeRange in incomeRanges"
      :label="incomeRange"
      :value="incomeRange"
      :key="incomeRange">
    </v-checkbox>

  </v-navigation-drawer>

</template>

<script>
import {
  mapGetters,
  mapActions
} from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'RightNavigationDrawer',
  props: {
    open: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      absolute: true,
      opacity: 0.8,
      overlay: true,
      selectedGenders: [],
      selectedIncomeRanges: []
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.getGenders()
    this.getIncomeRanges()
  },
  computed: mapGetters('customStore', [
    'genders',
    'incomeRanges'
  ]),
  methods: mapActions('customStore', [
    'getGenders',
    'getIncomeRanges'
  ])
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you would track the `loading` status in vuex so that it's available in all of your components, like your other vuex state.  In your store, create a `loading` boolean state.  Next, create a loading action that will be called in the component like:

```
loadData({ commit, dispatch }) {
  commit('SET_LOADING', true);
  const loader1 = dispatch('getGenders')
  const loader2 = dispatch('getIncomeRanges')
  Promise.all([loader1, loader2]).then(() => {
    commit('SET_LOADING', false);
  })
}
```

`Promise.all` takes an array of promises from your loading actions and will not resolve until all of those promises have resolved.  Just make sure that your `getGenders` and `getIncomeRanges` actions return promises as well.  Now, in your component, map only `loading` and `loadData`:

```
...mapState('customStore', ['loading']),
...mapActions('customStore', ['loadData'])
```

Change `mounted` to call this action:

```
mounted() {
  this.loadData()
}
```

Now you can check `loading` anywhere instead of `overlay` in all of your components.  This is a superior pattern because now `loading` is stored only once in vuex with your other state, and is available in all of your components, rather than being managed and passed locally.

[Here is a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/kofehbr0/) where I'm simulating AJAX calls with a timeout.  (The example uses a single file to manage vuex + vue so it will look slightly different, but shouldn't be too hard to follow.)

Answer (score 0):

Put a watch on `overlay` (getter from Vuex storage).Let say the value is `this.overlay = true`

```
watch: {
    overlay (val) {
      val && setTimeout(() => {
        this.overlay = false
      }, 3000)
    },
  },
```

Follow [code pen](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101)